# email using CDO in VFP values in variables

Tags: visual-foxpro, cdo.message

A question about this:

Why the value of each field of the object can't be a variable name?
In a Example this code works fine

```
With Flds
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
```

This code not working at all

```
With Flds
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = lnSendUsing
```

Comment: If there is a variable named lnSendUsing with a value like 2, and first one is working, then the latter would work too. Probably lnSendUsing doesn't have the value you think (prefix with m. to be sure that you mean a memory variable).

Comment: the variable lnSendUsing is previously declared and have a numeric value from the registry and is 2

Comment: I doubt it. Did you prefix with m. and did you debug?